# Databricks pyspark reading orc file, throws arrayindexexception when applying schema

Tags: pyspark, databricks, orc

I am trying to read a ORC format file which has 5000 rows in single file.

In databricks notebook, below command works

```
data_df = spark.read.format("orc").load(folder_path_of_orc_file)
display(data_df)  # prints the data in table foramt
data_df.count()  # prints 5000
```

Below command doesn't work

```
data_df = spark.read.format("orc").schema(my_schema).load(folder_path_of_orc_file)

display(data_df)  # throws exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Exception message

```
FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:/mnt/location/of/file/data-121098390284092.orc.
Caused by: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1024
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(FileScanRDD.scala:300)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:824)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:816)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:672)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1024
    at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$TreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$DecimalTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1322)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.ConvertTreeReaderFactory$DoubleFromDecimalTreeReader.nextVector(ConvertTreeReaderFactory.java:758)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:2059)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextBatch(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextKeyValue(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:333)
    ... 31 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2783)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2724)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2724)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1260)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1260)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1260)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2991)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2932)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2920)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1033)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2476)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:512)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3041)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectResult$1(Dataset.scala:3032)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3825)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3823)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3031)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:264)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:98)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.generateTableResult(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:524)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.computeListResultsItem(PythonDriverLocal.scala:672)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.genListResults(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:488)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$getResultBufferInternal$1(PythonDriverLocal.scala:727)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:608)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.getResultBufferInternal(PythonDriverLocal.scala:687)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.getResultBuffer(DriverLocal.scala:649)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.outputSuccess(PythonDriverLocal.scala:650)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$6(PythonDriverLocal.scala:221)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:608)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.repl(PythonDriverLocal.scala:208)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:541)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:518)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

One thing i noticed is that, the schema or header of the data in the orc file, had an incorrect spelling.

For example,
in orc file the schema or header is represented as below

```
column-hdr1 | column-hdr2 | column-hdr3
... .... ....
```

In the schema.json which is loaded using python, is defined  as column-header3 for column-hdr3.

Will above cause ArrayIndexOutofBound with 1024 rows.

I am new to Databricks and pyspark arena.

---

The schema i have looks like below

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "username",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "department",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {},
      "name": "loginname",
      "nullable": true,
      "type": "string"
    }
    ],
    "type" :"struct"
}
```

```py
## reading the schema and including lastupdateddate
## imported pyspark in different commandlet
import json
schema_dir = "/dbfs/FileStore/data-schema/"
schema_file = "user_schema.json"
user_data_schemas = {}
  print("reading schema, filename: ",schema_file)
  with open('{}/{}.json'.format(schema_dir, schema_file), 'r') as f:
    # read schema data file
    user_schema = T.StructType.fromJson(json.loads(f.read()))
    # add schema partition
    user_schema =  ( T.StructType(user_schema.fields + [T.StructField('lastupdateddate', T.IntegerType(), False)])
    )
    # list for schema
    user_schemas['user_data_schema'] = user_schema
    

user_data_df=(
    spark.read
    .format("orc")
    .schema(user_schemas['user_data_schema'])
    .load('/mnt/user-data/mycontainer/user/lastupdateddate' )
)
```

- The above code doesn't throw any exception.

```
 user_data_df.count()  # displays the count
 user_data_df.printSchema() # throws exception
```

Comment: can you please try to read it from other location and test it as Nested mounts are not supported. dbfs:/mnt/location/of/file/data this may cause . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#--mount-object-storage-to-dbfs

Comment: The orc file is present in Azure ADLS gen2 storage, so Databricks had a already mounted that path. So the interesting fact is. After applying the schema, `data_df.count()` returns data. only when i try to `display(data_df)` i get this issue. Mostly not sure whether this is an issue with the schema i am using.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with options . I could test it and works fine .

```
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/userdata1_orc"
file_type = "orc"

infer_schema = "false"
first_row_is_header = "false"
delimiter = ","

df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

[image]

Comment: in a way i understood what is wrong in my scenario, I am including an new column into the schema after reading it from the json file, but that is not present in the ORC file, i should have populated the records before using display() or show().

The `spark.read...` is performing a lazy loading, only when the `display() or show()` invoked over the dataframe the query is getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my scenario was, i included the lastupdateddate, in to the schema but the orc file didn't contains this column. - this was causing the issue

```py
user_schema = ( T.StructType(user_schema.fields + [T.StructField('lastupdateddate', T.IntegerType(), False)]))
```

When the `spark.read....` is executed, looks like it is performing a lazy loading.

When i use `display(dataframe)` or `dataframew.show()` it tries to read and map the actual orc file, which caused issue and was not able to map or convert correctly.

when using the `dataframe.printSchema()` there was not issue.

But luckily, when i was using `dataframe.describe()` was able to notice the hint of conversion issue.